# Nesting Wrappanel into DataGrid

Tags: wpf, datagrid, wrappanel

I am trying to nest a WrapPanel inside a DataGrid cell. What am I missing?

This is used to display sports team information.
A Team has a TeamName, a Coach, a Roster of Players where each player has a FullName.

More technically speaking, the Roster property is a ObservableCollection where PlayerViewModel has FullName property.

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Teams}">
   <DataGrid.Columns>
      <DataGridTextColumn Header="Team Name" Binding="{Binding TeamName}" />
      <DataGridTextColumn Header="Coach" Binding="{Binding Coach}" />
      <DataGridTemplateColumn>
         <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
               <WrapPanel DataContext="{Binding Roster}">
                  <Label Content="{Binding FullName}">
               </WrapPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
         </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
      </DataGridTemplateColumn>
   </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Comment: what doesnt work for you?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. This worked.

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn Width="150">
   <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
      <DataTemplate>
         <WrapPanel DataContext="{Binding Roster}">
            <Label HorizontalAlignment="Center" Content="{Binding Path=FirstName}" />
         </WrapPanel>
      </DataTemplate>
   </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
```